# awk lines greater than a specific value and include file name in output

Tags: awk

I need to find lines in hundreds of thousands of files that are greater than 200. Because I need to run it on so many files, I also need the output to include the file name. I can solve this problem for one file, but I can't seem to get the output to include the file name.

The values are in the second column of the file, and the delimiter is a space.

```
awk -F ' ' -v limit=200 '$2 >=limit' file
```

so ideally this would be

```
for i in *.txt    
do    
awk -F ' ' -v limit=200 '$2 >=limit' $i    
done
```

But also including the filename in the output. I've tried a bunch of stuff, but the results has been fun things like printing the file name 200 times or printing nothing at all.

Input:

```
1 4
1 968
2 500
1 0
1 0
1 0
```

Output:

```
filename 968
filename 500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like all you need is:

```
awk -v limit=200 '$2 >=limit{print FILENAME, $0}' *.txt
```